# What are the requirements to have the change your background feature enabled in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: windows, microsoft-teams, requirements, background

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780 mentions:

> Note: If you don't see this option in the menu, the feature might not be available on your device yet.

What are the requirements to have the change your background feature enabled in Microsoft Teams? I'm interested in Microsoft Windows.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running exactly? Are you running Teams within a VDI instance?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm also interested to know the Microsoft Windows version requirements to have the change your background feature enabled.

Comment: It might not matter but it's basic information you should share.

Comment: @Ramhound I have the option to choose the operating system. My options are Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate, 10 pro and 11 pro.

Comment: Are you running any of those versions in a VDI instance?

Comment: @Ramhound some are guests in virtual machines, some are installed directly on the computer.

Comment: That does not answer the very specific question I have about your Windows installation.  *Are these Windows installations running in a virtual desktop infrastructure?*  I have a very specific reason for asking if these your installations are running in a VDI.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, no VDI